# How do I allow a user to connect to the VPN but not through RDP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, remote-access, rdp

I have a windows 2008 server that is currently running a VPN.
There are a few user accounts that are used to connect to the VPN.

Now the problem is, in order to allow them to connect via VPN, I would have to enable remote access.
With enabling remote access, they would be able to connect via RDP.

Is there any way to only allow VPN access and not RDP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing about granting VPN access that allows RDP access to a server. Have you actually tried this with a standard user account? By default, only local administrators should have RDP access to a Windows server if you have it enabled.

Answer (score 2):

> Now the problem is, in order to allow them to connect via VPN, I would have to enable remote access. With enabling remote access, they would be able to connect via RDP.

Why? The only users that can RDP into a machine by default are users in the local Administrators group. If these aren't administrators on the server, then they won't be able to connect unless you explicitly add them to the Remote Desktop Users group.

Granting a user the ability to log into a VPN doesn't magically give them any other group membership on the server that they didn't already have.